# Swagger on Spring Boot: documentation is visible only on localhost

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

I went through many posts on this blog and elsewhere, but I didn't find the solution for my problem, so I hope you'll be able to help me and won't consider this post as a repetition of another one.
I developed a Spring Boot application and then added Swagger support, writing two configuration classes.

First one:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig
{   
     @Bean
        public Docket api() { 
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
              .select()                                  
//            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()) commentato per non visualizzare API relativi al percorso /error
              .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("it.ader.GestionaleSAL"))
              .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
              .build();                                           
        }
}
```

Second one:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport 
{
     @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/static/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
            super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
     }
}
```

Swagger works perfectly on localhost, at the address **http://localhost:8050/swagger-ui/index.html**.
Anyway, when my application was moved to remote server, I was given the remote URL in the form IP:port.
Then I tried from browser IP:port/swagger-ui/index.html, but I got an error page with following content:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Mar 08 17:36:30 CET 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Does anyone know how to make Swagger work even on remote server? Is additional configuration required?
Someboby states on web that this problem may depend on CORS problems.
In such case, how to verify this option and solve?

Thanks for support.

Comment: Do other URLs work? Are you sure the app is deployed on the server under the root `/` path?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I called one of exposed APIs from browser and it worked